# Image Inconsistency in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html5-canvas

Lately, I've been using HTML Canvas 5 element recently in an attempt to extract image data from a given image on the browser but I've run into a bit of a problem.  When extracting this data using the canvas element's functions such as getDataURL or getImageData(), the results are inconsistent across browser.  I realize this is due to the fact that the browser's native code is different for each, therefore the rendering engine will render the images differently.  However, is there a way to get consistent image results across browser for images of size 500kb-1mB for example?

I'm aware of the AJAX solution, calling the json object of the dataURL of that image from the server as that will be the original source, thus consistent across browser.  Also, loading the dataURL into the browser from the server could be another solution.  The problem with these would be the performance and flexibility.  Is there any other viable solutions?  Did I look over something I could be doing client side?

Thanks all!

Comment: By "consistent" do you mean "visually indistinguishable to the human eye" or "byte-for-byte identical"?

Comment: Byte for byte identical.  They are already visually indistinguishable as I'm using the same image on each browser.

Comment: What data format is it, are they compressed pictures?

Comment: What do you mean by "*calling the json object of the dataURL of that image from the server*"?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the images are in JPEG/PNG format.

Comment: I mean, I access the data URL of the image from the server as a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after continuing with my own project I discovered an answer which worked for me and would probably suit your purpose.

toDataURL was the mistake, because that reads the 'binary' data into the canvas and NOT the actual pixels. There are inconsistencies between browsers on interpreting that binary, and anyway that binary data is not giving you the pixel info which I assume you are looking for.

To preserve the data You need to take the image (keep original size) into the canvas then use getImageData(x,y,w,h) to load the RGBA pixel data into an array.  You can then simply loop through the now 'real' pixel data and process that.

I tried scaling down the image into a manageable size but that wasn't always consistent across browsers. I only needed a section of the image anyway so this method served my purpose, perhaps you could hide the full scale canvas you are working on and present a representative scaled down canvas to the user.